# cannot sync timedatectl (pi to PC)

Tags: ntp

when I type timedatectl I can see that sync is active. however the pi fails to get the time from a PC connected to it (on this pc the service W32time is running and should provide time info to all connected clients, this was configured as previously suggested on other forums, see here. I also tried to use NTPD but it was working for a day (enough to get offset pi-pc but failing to sync) and then it stopped. I also purged it because I have been told that ntpd has been deprecated on stretch.

I found the problem might be related to the pi not being able to communicate with the PC (which is however able to access the pi through VNC and ping it when directly connected through ethernet).

do not know why

Comment: What overrides have you put in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf to control which server timedatectl tries to access?

Comment: this is the line from my  /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf :                                    
[Time], NTP=141.20.67.78, FallbackNTP=0.debian.pool.ntp.org (commas are line separators here)

Comment: What's that 141.xx.xx.xx IP address? If you're trying to sync to your PC it should be the 172.xx.xx.xx, 10.xx.xx.xx or 192.168.xx.xx address of your PC. To sync to 141.xx.xx.xx you need an active route to the public internets.

Comment: the 141.x.x.x address is my local network IP for the pi. the PC has a similar one. I do not know how to set another IP for the pi. this is not my home network also

Comment: If it's not your network go and ask the network admins. They may have a timeserver you can use and can reach from your laptop and from your RPi.